# Pandas add a column and fill values by using list comprehension if else

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, nan

I want to add a column name `A` in `df`, and fill the values. If column `a1` has value, fill df.A with df.a1, else fill df.A with df.a2.

```
tm = pd.DataFrame({'a1':['astr1',np.nan,'astr2',np.nan],'a2':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'astr3']})
tm

    a1      a2
0   str1    NaN
1   NaN     NaN
2   str2    NaN
3   NaN     str2
```

I want this.

```
    a1      a2       A
0   str1    NaN      str1
1   NaN     NaN      NaN
2   str2    NaN      str2
3   NaN     str2     str2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask created by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
tm['A'] = np.where(tm.a1.isnull(), tm.a2, tm.a1)
print (tm)

      a1     a2      A
0  astr1    NaN  astr1
1    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  astr2    NaN  astr2
3    NaN  astr3  astr3
```

Another solutions with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
tm['A'] = tm.a1.combine_first(tm.a2)
print (tm)
      a1     a2      A
0  astr1    NaN  astr1
1    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  astr2    NaN  astr2
3    NaN  astr3  astr3
```

---

```
tm['A'] = tm.a1.fillna(tm.a2)
print (tm)
      a1     a2      A
0  astr1    NaN  astr1
1    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  astr2    NaN  astr2
3    NaN  astr3  astr3
```

And last solution with [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html):

```
tm['A'] = tm.a1
tm.A.update(tm.a2)
print (tm)
      a1     a2      A
0  astr1    NaN  astr1
1    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  astr2    NaN  astr2
3    NaN  astr3  astr3
```

Comment: Quite comprehensive. +1 sir.

Comment: Yes, I've accepted it. Thank you for helping. @jezrael

Answer (score 3):

In addition to jezraels answer, you can also use pandas [assign function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html). 
For example his fillna solution maybe recast in the form

```
tm.assign(A = lambda x:x.a1.fillna(x.a2))
```

This may be advantageous in pandas pipelines